# Java 8 Streams - collect multiple Integer fields from list of objects

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

For example I have a class:

```
public class Period {
    private Integer from;
    private Integer to;
}
```

And there is a list of objects in JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 2
    }, {
        "from": 3,
        "to": 4
    }, {
        "from": 5,
        "to": 6
    }
]
```

I want to collect from the `List<Period> periods`, all of the values from this two fields into one collection. In my case it would be `List<Integer> values`. Is there any possibility to use `stream` on `periods` list? I was trying to make something like this:

```
values = periods
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(p -> p.getFrom())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
values.addAll(
     periods
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(p -> p.getTo())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The result of this operation on previous JSON is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is there any any other option to manipulate over stream to accomplish the same result?

Comment: `.mapToInt(p -> p.getFrom()).boxed()` is equivalent to `.map(p -> p.getFrom())`. You are just needlessly unboxing and reboxing everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream over the periods, for each item create a new stream of both attributes, and flatten them.

```
periods.stream()
    .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p.getTo(), p.getFrom()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that this way:

```
List<Integer> list = periods.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> Stream.of(m.getFrom(), m.getTo()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of the code in your question is `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]` (instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`).

If you want that output, here's a way without using `Stream.flatMap`:

```
List<Integer> values = Stream.concat(
        periods.stream().map(Period::getFrom),
        periods.stream().map(Period::getTo))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to intermix `from` and `to` values, then the other answers should work.

As pointed out in the comments, there's no need to use `Stream.mapToInt` followed by `Stream.boxed`, as this unboxes and boxes integer values unnecessarily.